# 2012 nissan pathfinder/no start no crank

Tags: nissan, no-crank-no-start, can-bus

hello all and thank you for reading. I am working on a friends 2012 Nissan pathfinder that his mechanic gave up on after throwing some parts at it and not fixing it.  scanned it and its throwing a u1000 code.  It will not crank or start. I'm measuring the ohms on the can bus and its only 6 to 7 ohms, not the 60 or so it should be. I've disconnected the ecu, bcm, transmission control Module, instrument cluster, smart fuse block, Nissan vats system and a few other bits with no luck or change in ohms. I'm starting to think this thing may beat me. It were a short in the harness, I should have OL? What am I missing something? thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While I've not had much to do with the CAN Bus, just reading the U1000 code tells me it could possibly be any part which communicates over the CAN Bus, so I think you are on the right track for pulling modules. Anything which could communicate over the CAN Bus, including sensors, could be causing the issue and blocking transmission. I don't think it would be a short in the harness, but short of testing continuity wire-for-wire, I doubt you are going to find it if it is a short.

Comment: Sometimes we overlook things and jump to conclusions. This may be one of them, presuming the U1000 error code is preventing starter operation. Some vehicle antitheft systems will disable the starting circuit and maybe injector operation as a way to prevent theft. In any antitheft system, there's should be an indicator or digital display warning of a theft attempt. Does your

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we overlook things and jump to conclusions. This may be one of them, presuming the U1000 error code isn't preventing starter operation. Some vehicle antitheft systems will disable the starting circuit and maybe injector operation or ignition system as a way to prevent theft. In factory antitheft systems, there should be an indicator or digital display warning of a theft attempt. Does this '12 Pathfinder have an indicator informing you with a beep and/or indicator of; factory theft deterrent is ON, OFF, on standby (blinking) or flashing quickly (theft attempt with electronics disabled to prevent starting and driving away? This presumes all wiring and connections are intact before the error code occurred. If factory or aftermarket antitheft system aren't triggered to prevent starting, then this may be a starting problem related to; battery, battery cables their connections and main grounds between battery and engine block. Separating factory or aftermarket antitheft systems must be understood before proceeding with starting issues; starting circuit, fuel or spark problem. I tend to ignore an error code like this unless certain that it's pointing to a major wiring issue related to the two wire canbus connected to all modules and the error code is pointing to the factory antitheft system disabling starting. I try to use the simplest diagnosing routine using all information at hand before presuming an error code is pointing to a real fault. In this case, unless you know how this antitheft system operates to eliminate it in order to move on to a possible starting problem, you may be juggling too many what-ifs and getting lost.

Comment: I thank you for your response. I have removed the non factory remote start and alarm system. The factory system does show the ignition not seeing the key. This what the first shop focused on. They changed the BCM with a used unit, said they had another key cut and programmed for the car. They also changed the starter motor. I agree that this can have loads of different possibilities making it difficult.

Comment: Adding to the equation are all the removed parts and wires from the first shop. The Nissan TSB says to focus on the u codes before any of the others. That's why i was focusing on the 60 or 120 ohm reading of the bus line. Since it is not present, none of the modules(i think ) can communicate with each other.   i do appreciate any and all suggestions.

Comment: i have changed a damage fusible link by the battery, cleaned all the grounds and cables.

Comment: What a TSB states may have nothing to do with the error code at all since neither Nissan nor whoever's working on this problem may not have a clue and simply throwing parts at it in hopes of a fix. This fix failed and it's all on your dime. Any repair  shop will gladly continue as long as they're paid, regardless of a solution or not. Electronics in our vehicles can make it very difficult to anyone without extensive experience and knowledge. There's definitely a process of elimination as I've described without shotgunning for a fix. My experience? Electronics background in everyday problems.